# Can a website track what extensions a browser is running?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, browser-addons

I'm trying to find a way to track what extensions someone is using in their browser, but am unable to find any mention of this being possible. On the plus side, I don't see anything that says it's impossible.

I work in a tech support position and would like to send someone to a website where they will be able to easily send me a list of the extensions they are using. This would allow me to more easily troubleshoot problems (especially with folks who are on the lower end of tech awareness).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would assume so, as https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/plugincheck/ does it for Firefox.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6: that is for plugins, not *extensions*.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no way to track installed extensions.

You can [still detect](http://ctrlq.org/code/19818-detect-adblock-javascript) Adblock Plus and other similar extensions.